# Download weekly MP3 from RSS feed + rename the file (automation)

Tags: windows-xp, download, automation, rss

I want to automate downloading mp3 files from an RSS feed. Basically once a week a file needs to be downloaded, renamed and moved to a certain directory.

Is there any free software that can do this?

If not, I might try to figure out how to program it myself.

The OS is Windows XP.

Comment: It would help if you'd state your OS, I think it would be easy to write a cronscript for Linux.

Comment: If you're using Windows, then the OS has built-in capability for syncing RSS feeds and downloading attachments (`%windir\system32\msfeedssync.exe`). You can use IE or Windows Live Mail to subscribe to feeds; neither needs to be running for the downloading to happen. For the rename/move, you could probably write a batch or PowerShell script and schedule it with Task Scheduler (or even add it as a second action to the automatically created RSS sync task (`User_Feed_Synchronization-{GUID}`).

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention I'm using Win XP. That's added to the post now.

Comment: And can you elaborate a bit on how the renaming and moving should work?